# How to anyway escape ? charater in Django url?

Tags: django, regex, url

I know that '?' character is not recommended (permited?) in django urls, but one of my requirments is to process external calls like "/files/?access_token=" and i cannot change their syntax, so i need to process it.
I've tried:

```
1 re_path(r'(?P<filenamename>[^/]+)(.+)access_token', views.GetFileInfo, name='get_info')

2 re_path(r'(?P<filenamename>[^/]+)(\?)access_token', views.GetFileInfo, name='get_info')

3 re_path(r'(?P<filenamename>[^/]+)(?)access_token', views.GetFileInfo, name='get_info')

4 re_path(r'(?P<filenamename>[^/]+)?access_token', views.GetFileInfo, name='get_info')

5 re_path(r'(?P<filenamename>[^/]+)\?access_token', views.GetFileInfo, name='get_info')
```

But nothing above is a solution. Top url is working with other characters but not with question symbol. I'm starting to consider writing my own middleware (never did it) to change request's properties or  using  smth like url_rewrite, but all this looks like over-engineering of such simple task like processing a character.
Do i miss something?

Comment: This is not part of the path, this is the querystring, yo access these with `request.GET`.

Comment: to add: any occurence of ?-character leads to 404. There is no such promblem with othe r symbols, i've tested.

Comment: exactly, because the part after the `?` (the `?` included) is removed from the URL before checking what view to "fire", so if you add a `?` part, then it will never fire that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* part of the path, hence the `url`/`path` does not know about that. This is the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring). This is stored in [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) as a [**`QueryDict`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), a dictionary like object.

You can thus define the path as:

```
path('<str:magic_name>', views.GetFileInfo, name='get_info')
```

and in the view, obtain it with:

```
def GetFileInfo(request, magic_name):
    access_token = request.GET.get('access_token')
    # …
```

Comment: Hi, Willem!
There is no problem for me with getting parametres from urls, no. My problem is processing request with ?-symbol, i just  cannot build and url to catch such requests but i had to, because this is external requirment.

Comment: @Dadudki: well as said, these do *not* belong to the path part, so you *can* not *capture* these, since these are stripped from the url *before* matching it with a view.

Comment: Thank, William, i comprehended your post now, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use query_params to get the query string like:

```
access_token = request.query_params.get('access_token')
```

After that you can do get or filter operation on your model data according to your requiremnts.

Comment: This is only available, to the best of my knowledge, in the Django DRF Framework.[